# How to set constraints for UIButton ImageView Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a button and in its ImageView I am setting up the image of the user. I have set the position of imageView with UIImage Insets through Storyboard. But the problem come when Another user gets logged in, which means a different username and thus because of that, the image view's position gets disturbed, it gets shifted to either right left. How should I set imageView's constraints so that it stays in one position. Right Now it is on left side. Here are my images below.
[image: First Picture]
[image: Second Picture]

I have tried to set constraints programmatically like below but didn't worked.

```
profile.imageView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: profile.leadingAnchor, multiplier: -100.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `imageEdgeInsets` for achieving this.

```
profile.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 0) // adjust the inset values accordingly
```

Comment: Yes @Frankenstein sir, I ve already used these as I have mentioned. But no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
profile.imageView.image = yourUiImage?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -8, left: -8, bottom: -8, right: -8))
```

-8px are example values, use your own.

If your button bounds are dynamic - it's better for you to create custom class of UIButton and make all layout stuff with constraints inside your custom button.